# .htaccess: redirect access to a subdirectory, but without allow access root files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` that redirect all access to a specific subdirectory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it is my directory structure:

```
/public/index.php
/test.php
/.htaccess
```

If I access `http://domain.com/` it works normally by send all to `/public/index.php`. But if I access `http://domain.com/test.php` it run `test.php`. But I need avoid access to any root files.

And this script have another problem. If I try call a inexistent file, instead of send commands to `/public` and route it to a own 404 error (defined on `index.php` structure), it shows a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^public/index\.php$ public/index.php [L]
```